Transactional consistency in Delta lake
Does delta lake provide transactional level consistency? I know delta lake provide optimistic concurrency control for 2 concurrent operation, but I am talking about two concurrent transaction, not operations. Lets say my transaction is as follows
BEGIN TRANSACTION:
  1. read delta table version -> gives version 1
  2. perform some alter operation on delta table -> results in version 2
-- at this point some other transaction performs some operation on delta table resulting in version 3
  3. perform some alter operation on delta table -> results in version 4
  4. perform some operation on delta table which fails -> need to rollback whole transaction
END TRANSACTION

In this case we will need to roll back to version 1. This will also rollback version 3 which may result in some inconsistent state for other application. Does delta lake provide any way to avoid this? I also cannot use my own application level locking mechanism, since in this case delta table is expected to be modified by different applications and this modifications does not have single point of entry where locking can be implemented.
